# Attaching a VSCode Debugger to a Sub Process in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a script that effectively does the following:

top_script.py:

```
os.system("bash_script.sh")
```

bash_script.sh

```
python3 child_script.py
```

child_script.py

```
# Actual work goes here
```

In VSCode, I love the integrated debugger, but when I follow their advice[1] when launching from the IDE, I get "ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678".

When I execute the following from the integrated terminal in VSCode, it runs without the errors, but it doesn't stop on breakpoints in child_script.py.

```
python3 -m debugpy --listen 5678 top_script.py
```

How can I execute the top script first (either from the IDE or command line) and have breakpoints I attach in child_script.py be rendered in VSCode?

[1] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a configuration to your **launch.json** file like the following:

```
{
        "name": "MySubProcess",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
}
```

Now start your python process separately (via a prompt, or however).  This will generate a python subprocess.  You can see this in Windows Task Manager (or also in MacOS Activity monitor, or in Linux a similar way).

In VSCode, then click **Debug**, (select your subprocess configuration: "MySubProcess" in our example above), and then choose the process which was just started.  The debugger will then stop at the breakpoints in your subprocess code.

Comment: Outstanding! Exactly what I was looking for!

(Well, SPECIFICALLY, if i could name the subprocess so it automatically picked, that'd be even better)

Comment: Tried a lot of things but this was ultimately the solution for me in VS Code. I added like above, and then also put a delay in the subprocess script so I can attach after the pid is created. I did that with an input `input("Press Enter to continue...:")` before the breakpoints like suggested [here](https://pavolkutaj.medium.com/how-to-attach-debugger-to-python-script-called-from-terminal-in-visual-studio-code-ddd377d99456)

Answer (score 2):

I followed RexBarker's suggestion, but VSC always gave me an error of "Timed out waiting for debug server to connect". In order to find out the cause, the "log to file" was enabled in the Configuration like below,

```
{
    "name": "MySubProcess",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    "logToFile": true
}
```

Then I could find the detailed error in the log file on the VSC host, which is located at ~/.local/share/code-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501/debugpy.adapter-{pid}.log

It told me 'gdb' not found. After I installed gdb, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by using `os.system()` the debugger doesn't know you started another Python interpreter that you care about. What you will need to do is attach to the second process. Details will vary depending on how you want to set this up, but you can look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_local-script-debugging as a starting point.

Comment: OK! So then do I put this blob of code in the second script? And start it from the command line, then start VS Code debugging when it's paused?

Comment: Essentially, yes. You can also launch it from VS Code and it should wait for the other process to start (you can do "attach to process" if you launch it from the command line).

Answer (score 1):

Enabling logging as SZ Yang suggested helped to determine the problem. For me it was `ptrace: Operation not permitted`

To deal with it I ran `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` before running main script.

As I was a little confused how to make it work, here is what worked for me (after running preceding command). Let's say we have *main-script.py* and *sub-script.py*, invoked from main-script.py with `os.system()`. And we want to debug sub-script.py.

1. Insert `input("Continue...")` or similar in sub-script.py
2. Put a breakpoint in sub-script.py after input statement
3. Run from terminal main-script.py, until it reaches user input in sub-script.py
4. Run VSCode sub-process launch configuration and select python process which run sub-script.py
5. Provide any user input, or just press enter in terminal window

And breakpoint will be hit in sub-script.py, voila!